# inlineEditSupport in Safari browser

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport, ipad

I have a vf page where i have `apex:outputField` as a column in a table which is a picklist field. I have `inlineEditSupport` for the outputfield. When i try to edit that outputfield from desktop i could able to get drop down and value in that picklist. But when I try to do in Ipad safari browser i could not able to get dropdown and value in picklist.

Below is my code.

```
<apex:column  >
<apex:outputField value="{!c.Updated_plist__c}" >

<apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick"  / >
</apex:outputfield>
</apex:column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced inputfield with outputfield

Answer (score 1):

Since double-click event cannot be produced on iPad, we can use the 'mouse-over' event.

e.g.:

```
<apex:column>
  <apex:outputField value="{!c.Updated_plist__c}">
    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="onmouseover" />
  </apex:outputfield>
</apex:column>
```